# How to enable multiple column for a listbox on VB.NET web application?

Tags: vb.net, web-applications

What i'm trying to do is to display two columns on a listbox so the user has more information.
The way i fill the listbox is by using a SqlDataSource with a custom query and then i attach that Data Source to the list box.

My problem is in the Data Source i can only pick two values one for the listbox display and the other values is to select the datafield value for the list box.

How can i display multiple column values from a SqlDataSource on a Listbox?

Answer (score 0):

First create a Class for your data. I added a parameterized constructor so it would be easy to create a Coffee without separately setting properties. I also overrode the .ToString method so the ListBox would display what I want. If you really want columns you get into padding to a set length.

```
Public Class Coffee
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Sub New(cofName As String, cofType As String)
        Name = cofName
        Type = cofType
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name}, {Type}"
    End Function
End Class
```

To fill the list, create a new coffee and add it to the list.

```
Private CoffeeList As New List(Of Coffee)

Private Sub FillCoffeeList()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 10 Name, Type From Coffees;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                Dim c As New Coffee(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1))
                CoffeeList.Add(c)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Then in the Page.Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillCoffeeList()
        ListBox1.DataSource = CoffeeList
        ListBox1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

The ListBox calls .ToString on each Coffee object in CoffeeList and displays what we determined in the Class.